# Finding a series of previous highs (not higher highs) after a condition is met

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I've been working on this for the past week but can't see if figure out how to do this in Pine.  When only the most recent occurrence of a condition is true, how do I identity and reference the past 8 previous candle highs which is higher than the high[1] (ie, the candle prior to the trigger in my screenshot)?  They don't have to be higher highs.  The high of the historical candle must just be higher than the trigger -1 candle.  Hopefully this makes sense.

[image]

I've tried using for loops, valuewhen(), and a few other things but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the highest value of `high` on previous 8 bars, use `ta.highest()` function on each bar. Then you can get the value of `ta.highest` only when your condition is met, using `ta.valuewhen` function:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

highest8 = ta.highest(high, 8)
condition = ta.cross(ta.sma(close, 10), ta.sma(close, 20))
value = ta.valuewhen(condition, highest8[1], 0)

if condition
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(value), color = color.green, textcolor = color.white)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately your code isn’t quite what I need. It’s finding the highest high of the previous 8 bars.